# Adding cell row to int array

Tags: c#

I am currently trying to add a cell row into an int array. Can somebody point me in the right direction? I am able to add it to a string array as below but I am really struggling for the int array.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
DriverNames[z] = row.Cells[0].Value != null ? row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Int array:

```
FinishTime1 = new int[dataGridView1.Rows.Count]
```

Comment: use int.parse or Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())

Comment: What do you want to use if the value is null, `int.MinValue`, 0 or what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
DriverNames[z] = row.Cells[0].Value != null ? int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()) : 0;
```

Comment: @Telexx I am afraid that this one crashes for any non integer value. 5.5, for instance. You should intend to reduce the length of the code only when the reliability is not affected.

Comment: Integer values will only ever be passed here. It is looking at the hour part of a timestamp from a DB.

Comment: @Telexx OK, then. Just wanted to clarify this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
 DriverNames[z] = row.Cells[0].Value != null ?Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()) : 0;
```

If zero is valid entry Then array should be nullable so that we can insert null values in that array then expression becomes

```
int?[] DriverNames = new int?[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
DriverNames[z] = row.Cells[0].Value != null 
    ? Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString()) 
    : (int?)null;
```

Comment: `String.Empty` in an `int[]`?

Comment: What if zero is a valid value? How can you differentiate them?

Comment: Then your array should be nullable and add null if cells' value is null

Comment: It's not my question. But you should update your answer instead of commenting it since it is an important information.

Comment: But @TimSchmelter i tested in vs2010 casting makes no diffrence

Comment: `int?[] DriverNames = new int?[10]; DriverNames[0] = 1==1 ? int.Parse("1") : null;` This will not compile because both `int.Parse("1")` and `null` must be of the same type or they must be convertible to each other implicitly. Thats the rule for the conditional operator. Therefore you need to cast the  `null` to `int?` or use an `if-else` instead (btw, i'm also using VS2010).

Answer (score 1):

[Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), should do the trick from a string.

If `Value` is a `Decimal` try this:

```
(int)System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(dec).ConvertTo(dec, typeof(int));
```